# Beer is made ___ yeast, water, hops, and malted barley

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct answer to fill in the gap in "Beer is made ____ yeast, water, hops and malted barley"?

1. of
2. from
3. with
4. out of

I am leaning toward '2'. "Made from" can be used to describe a manufacturing process.

I originally liked '3', but I don't like it now. I would use '3' if I mentioned secondary ingredients, as in "This beer is made with raw apple cider."

Comment: "With" can also imply that the thing was not an ingredient at all. "Beer is made with an enormous vat".

Comment: Partial duplicate of ['Made of' vs. 'Made from'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/made-of-vs-made-from) (and yes, your instinct is confirmed there).

Comment: "Of" tends to imply that the ingredients are still there.  If you had yeast, water, hops, etc, all there in the bottle, i assure you it wouldn't look much like beer.  :)

Comment: This will surely vary wildly with regional dialect. As for what's *correct*.. any discussion would surely end (or not!) in a debate on what it is for a word choice to be correct. My instinct seeing only the title "made of .." (I'm from Dorset) - it only seemed questionable when I saw your actual ..question, and the options it presents.

Comment: @EricLippert I (from the UK) respectfully disagree and think the use of "made with" implies that the vat *is* an ingredient (though common-sense suggests it isn't).  I'd write "made in" or "made using" to avoid that implication.

Comment: Sounds like the [Reinheitsgebot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinheitsgebot). Also, "is composed of" would seem to be accurate - "made" doesn't *feel* right because it's ultimately a consumable liquid product.

Answer (score 24):

**Of** and **out of** both carry a slight implication that the beer is simply *assembled* from those ingredients, rather than crafted.

**With**, as you yourself hinted, implies that the listed ingredients are not the only - or even most important - components.

**From**, therefore, seems to be the logical choice.  That being said, the differences are very slight, and I doubt that anyone would correct you for choosing any of the others.

Comment: "implies that the listed ingredients are not the only - or even most important - components". Importance is a tricky issue when all ingredients are essential, but what's missing from the list is malted grain.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I didn't notice that - important omission!  I just assumed that the ellipses indicated that the list continued.  Definitely weakens my case against "with", doesn't it?

Comment: @SteveJessop: the question title always had "and malted barley" at the end.  When the title was first copied into the question body, the all-important "and malted barley" was replaced by an ellipsis.  I've copied the three words in place of the three dots.

Comment: And just to add a bit of detail, whether "with" is acceptable comes down to whether a brew made with the 4 ingredients, and another ingredient (like a spice, for example) counts as beer.  The German purity laws say no.  And lots of people say no.  But lots and lots of others don't particularly care.

Answer (score 7):

[to brew](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Brew) is the verb usually associated with beer:

> To make (ale or beer) **from** malt and hops by infusion, boiling, and fermentation.

[The process of brewing beer](http://www.sterkensbrew.be/sbm/beer_making.html).

Comment: That's not the question the OP was asking, but you _have_ contributed a vote for "from".

Comment: I guessed I highlighted the preposition 'from' clearly enough. Hope it is better now.

Answer (score 6):

Dorothy Sayers' *Murder Must Advertise* has a lovely paragraph where an advertising executive learns that he may not legally say cider was made *from* apples unless it has no other components, nor *out of* apples unless it is mainly apple juice, but fortunately he can say it was made *with* apples even if most of it comes from turnips. So which is "correct" depends both on how the beer was actually made and on how you wish to imply it was made.

(Note to eager advertising executives and lawyers: though Sayers' research was impeccable, it was in Britain some eighty years ago.)

Comment: I think that this very passage was floating in the back of my mind when I wrote my answer - thank you for reminding me what it was!  Love that book, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Beer is made ***from***...

*New Oxford American Dictionary* provides a definition that fits *the exact context*:

> **from (preposition)**: 6) indicating the raw material out of which
>   something is manufactured

Answer (score 1):

What others have said already is true. All words work here but I think there is rather a strong argument for **with**. As you've already noted, **with** can make the list seem incomplete and in your example (where you're listing one ingredient of a specific beer) that works fine.

But I don't consider this a fault. If anything, because unspecified "beer" can be made with a huge number of different ingredients, to suggest an open-ended list is more accurate. Other forms might suggest that if you have more ingredients you're no longer making beer.

If, however, we're listing *all* the ingredients for a *specific* beer, I'd vote for **of** or **from**.
Both sound natural when I say them to myself.

Answer (score 1):

*Of* works but has (to me) a hint of that you couldn't be bothered to find a more specific word.

*From* is best, and only weakly implies an exhaustive list.  "Beer is made from (among other ingredients) malt and hops" is perfectly sensible with or without brackets. Especially as water is a rather obvious ingredient.

*With* is just too vague - it could even be taken to mean "in the same factory as", e.g. "beer is made with cider in a brewery" (UK meaning of cider).

*Out of* has the flaws of *of* but a stronger suggestion of exclusivity.

Strictly speaking beer is brewed *from* malted barley and water, *using* yeast, and only *flavoured with* hops, however it would seem sensible to ignore this distinction as the hops are fundamental to beer.  The yeast is not an ingredient in the cooking sense - it takes an active part in the process.

Comment: It's flavoured *by* hops, surely :-P

Answer (score 1):

I would try option E in this case:

> "Beer is made **using** yeast, water, hops..."

Although to be honest I might be tempted to be a bit more verbose as per Josh61's answer:

> "Beer is produced **by brewing** yeast, water, hops..."

Comment: But you don't brew yeast.

Answer (score 1):

My first gut-feeling was "from", but lest this devolve to a poll, I lean toward Josh61 and maaarghk that you need a different *verb* (instead of *make*), rather than a different *preposition* (in place of your blank).

I think the preferable answer to this broadened question depends on the context in which you're using the sentence. Are you writing a manual on beer brewing? Are you contrasting other fermented products (e.g., bread) or other beverages (e.g., lemonade)? Other verbs or prepositions might be more advisable, depending on context.  If you're still interested, would you kindly expand on the context of the sentence? Or an accepted answer could terminate the conversation in a different direction.

Aside from that, I suggest that you also include the word "delicious" somewhere in that sentence... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"W **made of** X, Y, Z" is used for materials/ingredients (X, Y, Z) that don't change their characteristics during the process of creating W.

> Chairs are **made of** wood.

"W **made from** X, Y, Z" are used for materials/ingredients (X, Y, Z) that are transformed during the process of creating of W and lose their characteristics during this.

> Wine is **made from** grapes.

There are more details in a similar question regarding [made of vs made from](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/made-of-vs-made-from/65909).

Probably (4) (out of) might substitute "made from", but (3) (with) is certainly not an option here.

Comment: medica, thank you pointing out at this. Will expand my answer.